# How to add ip allias to GKE + GitLab Runner?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

I deployed Heml Chart gitlab/gitlab on GKE

```
helm install gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
  --set global.hosts.domain=**my.domain.tld** \
  --set certmanager-issuer.email=me@example.com
```

then integrated GKE with GitLab.
[Integration succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5xe4.jpg)
But automatically created Runner's pod fails on registration with error

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 
status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.my.domain.tld/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://gitlab.my.domain.tld/api/v4/runners: dial tcp: 
lookup gitlab.my.domain.tld on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host
```

How i can change Runner's /etc/hosts? Or add some system variable with ip to gitlab.my.domain.tld?

P.S. Also i tried to use Helm Chart gitlab/gitlab-runner with config,

```
helm install gitlab-runner -f values.yaml gitlab/gitlab-runner
```

```
# values.yaml

gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.my.domain.tld/
runnerRegistrationToken: <token>
concurrent: 10
rbac:
  create: true
  clusterWideAccess: false
runners:
  image: ubuntu:18.04

hostAliases:
  - ip: <ip_of_my_gitlab>
    hostnames:
      - "gitlab.my.domain.tld"
```

but it fails on registration with another error

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 
runner=ipdNGq79 status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.my.domain.tld/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://gitlab.my.domain.tld/api/v4/runners: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

May be fix this issue easier then configure automatically created Runner's pod?
Where i can get needed certificate?
Thanks!

Comment: --set global.hosts.domain=**my.domain.tld**  - here i tried set bold style, sorry